# How to disable specific jquery-ui selectmenu choices?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I understand how to disable the entire selectmenu.

But I just want to disable a few of the options within it. How can I do it..?

Comment: Add your code here, it will help us to suggest you in quick rather doing whole exercise again.

Answer (score 8):

The documentation reads:

> The Selectmenu widgets provides a styleable select element replacement. **It will act as a proxy back to the original select element**, controlling its state for form submission or serialization

(*emphasis mine*).

Which means you can simply add the `disabled` attribute to the `<option>`'s you want to disable in the HTML and it'll be reflected in the widget once it is initialized.

---

Regarding the the changes you make dynamically to the *original* `<select>` element, it will not be reflected immediately in the widget - because as one can possibly imagine, constantly querying the `DOM` for changes in the original `<select>` is likely to cause a performance hit.

Hence we have the following:

### [refresh](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh)

> Parses the original element and re-renders the menu. Processes any  or  elements that were added, removed or disabled.

All we have to do is, make the changes to original `<select>` and call refresh.

In this case, we should target the options to disable using corresponding [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), disable them using [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) and then call refresh, as shown below:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#speed").selectmenu();
  $("#first").attr("disabled", true); // any other selector as you wish
  $("#speed").selectmenu("refresh");
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<label for="speed">Select a speed</label>
<select name="speed" id="speed">
  <option id="first">Slower</option> <!-- disabled by dynamically-->
  <option>Slow</option>
  <option selected="selected">Medium</option>
  <option disabled>Fast</option> <!-- disabled by default-->
  <option>Faster</option>
</select>
```